# Symlink directory with content

Tags: mount, symlink, readonly

So I have `/usr` as `'ro'` filesystem (cannot change that, work rules and security) and I have another directory `/bigdata` which is `'rw'`.

I'm installing some services but it needs to write in `/usr/foo`, so I thought I could symlink to `/bigdata`. The problem is I have other files in `/usr/foo`.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't include copying all content of `foo`in`bigdata`?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS).

Comment: For logical separation of the data, a dedicated directory might be wise to do, in addition to simplifying the filesystem management. Or just symlink _all_ the files... The question is also what OS you are on, different systems may have different "advanced" features.

Comment: As `/usr` is on a ro filesystem, how would you want to create a symlink there?

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to override `/usr/foo` but only for the misbehaving application. The misbehaving application would see `/usr/foo` as an alias for `/bigdata` but every other process in the system would continue to see `/usr/foo`'s real contents including the files that are actually in there. This assumed the misbehaving application doesn't care that the normal contents of `/usr/foo` are inaccessible to it.

```
sudo unshare --mount sh -c 'mount --make-rprivate / &&
    mount -n --bind /bigdata /usr/foo &&
    exec su "$SUDO_USER" -c misbehaving_application'
```

(Tested)

Otherwise, [OverlayFS](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) might solve your problem, as suggested in the comments.

Finally, as a last resort, some symlink gymnastics can do the trick. The idea would be to:

- bind mount a copy of `/usr/foo` somewhere else

  ```
  mkdir /writable/place/foo
  mount --bind /usr/foo /writable/place/foo
  ```
- Squash `/usr/foo` with your replacement directory

  ```
  mount --bind /bigdata /usr/foo
  ```
- Symlink the existing files so they can be accessed from /usr/foo

  ```
  for x in /writable/place/foo/*; do
    ln -s "$x" /usr/foo
  done
  ```

(Not tested)